# In the Nuremberg Laws, What did "Approved for Citizenship" is half Jewish mean in practice?

Tags: nazi-germany, jews

An example: Hans Bethe was a very well-regarded physicist and a half-Jew by Nuremberg definition which further states that he is "approved for Reich citizenship": *[Nuremberg Citizenship Laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuremberg_Laws#Reich_Citizenship_Law)*

It is clear that "approved" is different than "belongs to German race." Bethe did not consider himself Jewish but was promptly relieved of his professorship and while he managed to stay in Germany for a while, he soon came to the USA.

Why was this part of the laws? Was it because it was not very hard to get this approval? If it required special action by Hitler himself (the honorary Aryan thing) I assume Hitler could have granted this to a Hasidic rabbi.

Bethe seems like the kind of person who would have managed to get citizenship and if so, would have needed a job. So just what did this phrase in the Nuremberg Laws mean in practice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It is clear that "approved" is different than "belongs to German race."

Under "approved" (which is the phrase used in the Wikipedia article) should be understood as

- when certain conditions are fulfilled

These conditions are defined in §2(2) of the **The First Ordinance on the Reich Citizenship Law of November 14, 1935** quoted below.

If up to 2 grandparents are Jewish **and** none of the conditions of §5(2) are fulfilled, the person could remain a citizen of the Reich (Reichsbürger).

Since Hans Bethe was living in the US when this Ordinance was issued in November 1935, it probably didn't effect him.

---

> **Die Erste Verordnung zum Reichsbürgergesetz vom 14. November 1935**
> Auf Grund des § 3 des Reichsbürgergesetzes vom 15. September 1935 (Reichsgesetzbl. I S. 1146) wird folgendes verordnet:
>
> > **The First Ordinance on the Reich Citizenship Law of November 14, 1935**
> > On the basis of Section 3 of the Reich Citizenship Act of September 15, 1935 (Reichsgesetzblatt I p. 1146), the following is decreed:
>
> **§ 1**
> (1) Bis zum Erlaß weiterer Vorschriften über den Reichsbürgerbrief gelten vorläufig als Reichsbürger die Staatsangehörigen deutschen oder artverwandten Blutes, die beim Inkrafttreten des Reichsbürgergesetzes das Reichstagswahlrecht besessen haben, oder denen der Reichsminister des Innern im Einvernehmen mit dem Stellvertreter des Führers das vorläufige Reichsbürgerrecht verleiht.
> (2) Der Reichsminister des Innern kann im Einvernehmen mit dem Stellvertreter des Führers das vorläufige Reichsbürgerrecht entziehen.
>
> > (1) Until further regulations on the Reich Citizenship Certificate are issued, those nationals of German or related blood who possessed the right to vote in the Reichstag when the Reich Citizenship Law came into force, or who were granted provisional Reich citizenship by the Reich Minister of the Interior in agreement with the Deputy of the Führer, are provisionally considered Reich Citizens.
> > (2) The Reich Minister of the Interior can withdraw provisional Reich citizenship in agreement with the Deputy Fuehrer.
>
> **§ 2**
> (1) Die Vorschriften des § 1 gelten auch für die staatsangehörigen jüdischen Mischlinge.
> (2) Jüdischer Mischling ist, wer von einem oder zwei der Rasse nach volljüdischen Großelternteilen abstammt, sofern er nicht nach **§ 5 Abs. 2** als Jude gilt. Als volljüdisch gilt ein Großelternteil ohne weiteres, wenn er der jüdischen Religionsgemeinschaft angehört hat.
>
> > (1) The provisions of § 1 also apply to nationals who are Jewish half-breeds.
> > (2) A Jewish half-breed is someone who descends from one or two grandparents who are fully Jewish in terms of race, unless they are considered a Jew according to **§ 5 Para. 2**.  A grandparent is automatically considered fully Jewish if he or she belonged to the Jewish religious community.
>
> ...
> **§ 5**
> (1) Jude ist, wer von mindestens drei der Rasse nach volljüdischen Großeltern abstammt. § 2 Abs. 2 Satz 2 findet Anwendung.
> **(2)** Als Jude gilt auch der von zwei volljüdischen Großeltern abstammende staatsangehörige jüdische Mischling,
> a) der beim Erlaß des Gesetzes der jüdischen Religionsgemeinschaft angehört hat oder danach in sie aufgenommen wird,
> b) der beim Erlaß des Gesetzes mit einem Juden verheiratet war oder sich danach mit einem solchen verheiratet,
> c) der aus einer Ehe mit einem Juden im Sinne des Absatzes 1 stammt, die nach dem Inkrafttreten des Gesetzes zum Schutze des deutschen Blutes und der deutschen Ehre vom 15. September 1935 (Reichsgesetzbl. I S. 1146) geschlossen ist,
> d) der aus dem außerehelichen Verkehr mit einem Juden im Sinne des Absatzes 1 stammt und nach dem 31. Juli 1936 außerehelich geboren wird.
>
> > (1) A Jew is someone who descends from at least three grandparents who are fully Jewish by race.  § 2 paragraph 2 sentence 2 applies.
> > **(2)** A Jewish half-breed who is a citizen of the state and is descended from two fully Jewish grandparents is also considered a Jew,
> > a) who belonged to the Jewish religious community at the time the law was issued or is subsequently admitted to it,
> > b) who was married to a Jew at the time the law was passed or who subsequently married a Jew,
> > c) who comes from a marriage with a Jew within the meaning of paragraph 1, which was concluded after the entry into force of the law for the protection of German blood and German honor of September 15, 1935 (Reichsgesetzblatt I p. 1146),
> > d) who came from extramarital relations with a Jew within the meaning of paragraph 1 and was born after July 31, 1936, out of wedlock.

---

**Sources**:

- [Erste Verordnung zum Reichsbürgergesetz – Wikisource](https://de.wikisource.org/wiki/Erste_Verordnung_zum_Reichsb%C3%BCrgergesetz)

Comment: Thanks. Complex but it seems very easy for a half Jew to be classified as Jewish because of the Jewish community thing which was probably more prevalent in the 19th century than in the 20th -- Jews were I think up to 1848 forced to be part of the Jewish community or if not forced, tended to live among Jews. Maybe I am wrong about this, but maybe the law was designed to classify many half Jews. Not sure why they care about race AND religion of grandparents unless they felt descendants of observant Jews would be more disloyal.

Comment: @releseabe Considering that first draft of that law - which was based on US South Jim Crow Laws - was to define Jew as someone who had any Jewish in one's ancestry, it is not a surprise that there had to be something arbitrary to the law as passed. Because it would impact something on the order of 70% of the population, the first draft was rejected and they toned the criteria down. It is logical they went with religious expression instead - that was a much nicer and cleaner trait on which to discriminate. Obviously.

Comment: @AcePL Based on the census data from the 16th of June 1933, there were 492682 Jews (98747 ,19.8%, of which held non german passports) out of a total population of 65362115. That is 0.754%. [Volkszählung von 1933 - Jüdische Bevölkerung in Deutschland am 16.6.1933 Page 5/14 (Image) - Statistik des Holocaust](https://www.statistik-des-holocaust.de/VZ1933-8.jpg) Please supply a source for your claim: 'Because it would impact something on the order of 70% of the population,...', which would be over 45 million. This is very unlikely.

Comment: @MarkJohnson - the consideration initially was: if you had a Jewish ancestor, you are a Jew. Note that it didn't say: until x generation back; it said: any. It was called "one drop" rule. It would immediately concern about 1 million Jews as per regime's knowledge, but literally unknown number of people who didn't even knew would be Jews under that rule, but which could be enormous.... But I admit 70% was purely from memory and I can't remember from where it came nor any source that would  be even mention any number, let alone 70%. That I take back.

Comment: @AcePL The census data from the 16th of June 1933, shows less than a half million (492682) and that of 17th of May 1939 298604.

Comment: @MarkJohnson - *Hitler’s American Model* by James Q. Whitman mentions this: "By the official Nazi reckoning in 1935 there were 550,000 full and three-quarter Jews, 200,000 half Jews, and 100,000 quarter Jews in Germany."

Comment: @AcePL Since these categories were only definded in November 1935 these numbers didn't exist at the September 1935. The census data of 1933 and 1939 (where these categories were counted for the first time) should be used. [Volkszählung im Deutschen Reich 1939 – Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volksz%C3%A4hlung_im_Deutschen_Reich_1939#Angaben_zu_%E2%80%9EJuden%E2%80%9C)

Comment: @AcePL See also: [Jüdischer Mischling – Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/J%C3%BCdischer_Mischling#Zahlenangaben): *The number of Jews living in Germany was greatly overestimated by the National Socialists.  In 1935, Reich physician leader Leonardo Conti and the Reich Ministry of the Interior erroneously assumed that, in addition to the “full Jews”, there were 750,000 “half-breeds” living in Germany.*

Comment: @AcePL Here also are numbers showing 1933: 561000 ; 1935: 441700 ; 1939: 276700 [Jüdische Bevölkerung in Deutschland - Statistik des Holocaust](https://www.statistik-des-holocaust.de/stat_ger_pop.html)